# MIPS Load Word Placing

Tags: assembly, mips

I have a question regarding load words from an array in MIPS.
If an array "A" starts with memory location of 100h, and I'd like to load the word into a register, would it be fine if I do something like,

```
lw $t0, 0x100($t2)
```

despite the offset place being the memory location, and the offset ($t2) being in the base address? The way I see it is $t2 + 0x100 vs 0x100 + $t2.
Or is the only correct way is doing

```
lw $t0, $t2(0x100)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` is commutative, and the hardware only cares what the final address is.

The asm source syntax only allows `constant(reg)` so write it that way as `A($t2)`, of course.

The machine code would be the same either way if the other syntax were allowed; there's only one form of the `lw` instruction, and that's I-type with a register and a 16-bit immediate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! So just to be sure, it would be totally fine to write `lw $t0 0x100($t2)` regarding load word correct? Which is literally similar to accessing an array's element like A[I], but instead of brackets its parentheses?

Comment: @ApeOut: yes, but remember that asm works with *byte* offsets (not C array indices), and a word is 4 bytes.  So you'd need `add $t2, $t2, 4` to advance the index to the next element.  So yes, *similar*, like you said, not identical.